# MatrixExp[] for 4 by 4 matrix gives an unavailable answer

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

```
    Q = ( {
   {-7, 1, 2, 4},
   {2, -4, 1, 1},
   {2, 2, -6, 2},
   {1, 1, 1, -3}
  } )
    MatrixExp[Q*t]
```

I defined the matrix Q and executed the command. Then I got a result

```
{{-(248/137) - 59/274 Root[274 + 130 # + 20 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0] - (
   248 E^(t Root[274 + 130 # + 20 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0]))/(
   137 + 130 Root[274 + 130 # + 20 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0] + 
    30 Root[274 + 130 # + 20 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0]^2 + 
    2 Root[274 + 130 # + 20 #^2 + #^3& , 1, 0]^3) - (... and so on.)
```

Is there a way to obtain a cleaner form of the matrix exponential?

Comment: I would argue it is the cleanest form possible. In order to calculate the matrix exponential you need to diagonalize it. You have a matrix 4x4, the diagonalization requires solution of a 4th order algebraic equation, which is not simple.

Comment: ToRadicals[MatrixExp[Q*t]] // Simplify

Comment: `MatrixExp[Q*t] // FullSimplify` will give a much shorter form while still using `Root` expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exponential of a matrix is based on finding its eigenvalues. For a $4\times 4$ matrix these eigenvalues are the roots of a 4th order polynomial. That's why you see the `Root` function there. You would get the numerical result by applying [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

If you are looking for an exact solution, first you should determine whether the eigenvalues have any exact form or so. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is:

```
Factor@CharacteristicPolynomial[{{-7, 1, 2, 4}, {2, -4, 1, 1}, {2, 2, -6, 2}, {1, 1, 1, -3}}, x]

(** x (274 + 130 x + 20 x^2 + x^3) **)
```

now you can see that apparently, $x (x^3+20x^2+ 130 x + 274)$ has no integer/rational solution other than $0$, hence the excessive use of `Root` function in your answer.